# How to split a string based on element in C

Tags: c, sorting, split

I was working on my C project and trying to figure out something simple. How to split a string based on it's char element. I know this sounds really easy and I know it is. But I'm getting this really odd occurrence and I don't know what to do about it.

Code:

```
char str[999] = "Hello World> This is a test";

    char cursort[12];
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cursort[i] = str[i];
    }

    int u = 999 - 12;
    char leftover[u];
    for(int i = 1; i < u + 1; i++)
    {
        leftover[i - 1] = str[i + 11];
    }

    printf("%s\n", cursort);
    printf("%s\n", leftover);
    getchar();
```

Output:

```
Hello World>Hello World> This is a test
 This is a test
```

All i want is the first 12 characters to be on one line and the rest to be on a separate line.

Comment: I have trouble understanding what your code is even attempting to do.

Comment: Pretty sure at a glance that you are reading off the end of the `str` array.  Making a dynamic array for `leftover` is also done in a not completely portable way.  Honestly, also really not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  So I fall back to "walk through it in a debugger and see if it does what you want."

Comment: sorry. I realize my post isn't making so much since I will try to make it easier to understand what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Need to NUL terminate your strings too.  If array is 12 length, last value must be 0.

Comment: What is NUL? Sorry if i sound stupid but I just started C about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: If you want to copy the first 12 characters of the string into `cursort`, firstly, `cursort` needs to be big enough to hold all those characters plus the null terminator.  Secondly, you'll want to use the `strncpy` to do the copy rather than rolling your own copy loop.

Comment: And finally, rather than copying the entire rest of the string into another string, you can just pass in a pointer to the point in the string you wish to start printing from.

Comment: @JohnO'Meara The NUL terminator is a zero byte that marks the end of a string. All of the C string functions (including `printf`) expect a NUL terminator at the end of the string. For example, `cursort[11] = '\0';` would put a NUL terminator in the last byte of the `cursort` array.

Comment: char buf[size]={0}; strncpy(buf, str, 12); strcat(buf, "\n"); strcat(buf, str+12); printf("%s\n", buf);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all, I've removed your dynamic array.  Next, I've tried to keep as much of your code as possible for clarity while showing what is going on with comments.

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[999] = "Hello World> This is a test";

    // Make a string for the first 12 elements.
    char cursort[13];
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        cursort[i] = str[i];
    }

    // Terminate it.
    cursort[12] = '\0';

    // Make an array for the remaining data on the stack
    // Size is 12 less than original plus one for terminator.  This should be a constant or a #define
    char leftover[999 - 12 + 1];

    // Copy str into leftover offset by 12.
    for(int i = 12; i<999; i++)
    {
        leftover[i - 12] = str[i];
    }

    // Make sure it is terminated.
    leftover[999] = '\0';

    // Print it
    printf("%s\n", cursort);
    printf("%s\n", leftover);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

The biggest change is how I've setup your second loop.  I would also add that doing string manipulations like this is very error prone.  You'd be better off using built in routines to handle this.

Comment: What built in routines would you suggest for this particular problem?

Comment: `strcpy()`, `strncpy()` come to mind, though they only replace the for loops.  You'd still need to do some pointer work.  If the split were for printing only, then you could get away with not having any secondary strings.

Comment: BTW, style-wise, if I were to check this in, I would be laughed out of the office.  Take a look at "Magic Numbers" when you get a chance.  Right now, if I wanted to change where the "break" in the string was, I would need to change every number.  If I had made constants, it would only require a single change.  This is much easier to maintain and less error-prone in general.

Answer (score 0):

Something is up with your second loop. Try this.

```
        int u = 999 - 12;
        char leftover[u];
        for (int i = 0; i < u; i++)
        {
            leftover[i] = str[i + 12];
        }
```

Comment: Nope still, same result

Answer (score 0):

well the second loop you could start from 0 and avoid subtracting 1. start the iterator from 12 and you might want to do it

for (int i = 0; str[i + 12] != 0x00 ; i++)

That way you avoid doing X number of iterations just copying nulls.

Comment: could validate for null on the first for loop too

Comment: Still, same result